# Minicom corrects device file behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I have a device that gives data in **"\rAPDADF\r\n"** where the initial \r should be there and suffix "\r\n" should also be there.
The device file has \n instead of \r(screenshot attached).However, while reading data via minicom it is absolutely fine,( I see \r (0d in hex where it has to be) and after using minicom the device file shows data with \r.

Q- Please help me to understand how this file behaviour changed?

[image: Device file without \r]

[image: Minicom showing 0d(=~\r)]

[image: Device file after using minicom]

Comment: Is there a reason why you added the python tags?

Comment: @ewong, yes at python code level this behaviour is observed if I use open library,serial library and open library in order.